# JVM optimizations for `PermittedSubclasses`

Tags: java, optimization, jvm

Sealed classes/interfaces were added to Java with [JEP 360](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/360). The JVM-level change was to add a `PermittedSubclasses` attribute to class files, which can be used to explicitly list out which classes are allowed to extend a given class/interface.

1. Is this information something an optimizing runtime can rely on (eg. can it be counted on to be precise/checked?)
2. If the answer to 1 is "yes", do any widely used VMs actually use this? (Or are there any plans/papers about what is intended?)

I've read through the [Sealed Classes SE15 spec change](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se15/preview/specs/sealed-classes-jvms.html) and I think the answer to 1 is "yes", but I couldn't find anything in the way of optimizations in https://github.com/openjdk/jdk.

Comment: In fact, this attribute does not give the JVM more information (wrt. optimization) besides it already has. It does not matter what are *permitted* subclasses, when the JVM knows the complete actual hierarchy of all loaded classes at any moment of time.

Comment: Even if the JVM knows the complete hierarchy at a moment in time, loading new classes can invalidate a previous hierarchy, right? I think this is analogous to `final` methods vs. regular methods: the JVM can more aggressively inline the `final` method because it never needs to worry about a subclass with an override being loaded in later.

Comment: Once CHA assumptions are invalidated due to class loading, the corresponding optimized code is invalidated as well, allowing affected methods to be re-compiled with the new knowledge.

Comment: Basically, it’s like with the `final` flag of a class: very simple JVMs might benefit from it whereas sophisticated JVMs might only learn from it that they don’t need to take care for de-optimization triggers which might have a very tiny impact. Mind that to optimizers, the most important question is whether a particular method invocation might end up at a different implementation which more than often is false even when subclasses exist in the current runtime. So utilizing the `PermittedSubclasses` would affect a very small percentage only.